# Check if the series $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{\ln^{100}n}{n}\sin\frac{n\pi}{4}$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Which test should I use to check that the series $$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{\ln^{100}n}{n}\left(\sin\frac{n\pi}{4}\right)$$ converges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test) provides an efficient way: the sequence $\left\{\sin\frac{\pi n}{4}\right\}_{n\geq 1}$ has bounded partial sums and $\frac{\log^{100}n}{n}$ is decreasing to zero from some point on.